# Docker не хочет запускаться

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

Установил Docker по [этому](https://losst.ru/ustanovka-docker-na-ubuntu-16-04) гайду.
Если коротко по шагам то:

1. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
2. `sudo apt install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual`
3. `sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common`
4. `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -`
5. `sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"`
6. `sudo apt update && apt-cache policy docker-ce`
7. `sudo apt install -y docker-ce`

При проверке `sudo systemctl status docker` выдаёт

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Вс 2020-12-13 08:32:40 MSK; 5min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 26821 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1
 Main PID: 26821 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

дек 13 08:32:37 mirninec systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
дек 13 08:32:37 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
дек 13 08:32:37 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
дек 13 08:32:40 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
дек 13 08:32:40 mirninec systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
дек 13 08:32:40 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
дек 13 08:32:40 mirninec systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
дек 13 08:32:40 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
дек 13 08:32:40 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

При наборе `sudo journalctl -xe` выдаёт

```
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Произошел сбой юнита docker.service.
--
-- Результат: failed.
дек 13 08:40:43 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
дек 13 08:40:43 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
дек 13 08:40:45 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
дек 13 08:40:45 mirninec systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Завершена остановка юнита docker.service.
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Процесс остановки юнита docker.service был завершен.
дек 13 08:40:45 mirninec systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: Начинается запуск юнита docker.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Начат процесс запуска юнита docker.service.
дек 13 08:40:45 mirninec dockerd[26936]: time="2020-12-13T08:40:45.961800363+03:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
дек 13 08:40:45 mirninec dockerd[26936]: time="2020-12-13T08:40:45.969042080+03:00" level=fatal msg="Your Linux kernel v
дек 13 08:40:45 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
дек 13 08:40:45 mirninec systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Ошибка юнита docker.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Произошел сбой юнита docker.service.
--
-- Результат: failed.
дек 13 08:40:45 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
дек 13 08:40:45 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
дек 13 08:40:48 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
дек 13 08:40:48 mirninec systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Завершена остановка юнита docker.service.
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Процесс остановки юнита docker.service был завершен.
дек 13 08:40:48 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
дек 13 08:40:48 mirninec systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Ошибка юнита docker.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Произошел сбой юнита docker.service.
--
-- Результат: failed.
дек 13 08:40:48 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.socket: Unit entered failed state.
дек 13 08:40:48 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
дек 13 08:40:48 mirninec systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
дек 13 08:40:57 mirninec sudo[26944]: mirninec : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/mirninec ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -x
дек 13 08:40:57 mirninec sudo[26944]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by mirninec(uid=0)
```

Мой `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Гугл не помог. Или я неправильно спрашивал.
Вобщем как запустить Docker?

Comment: Пробовали - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100641/docker-service-start-failed ?

Comment: Поставить его по официальному гайду. https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: само сообщение об ошибке вы как раз и обрезали: `level=fatal msg="Your Linux kernel v`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто ответил. Дальнейшие танцы с бубном показали, что всё дело было в устаревшем ядре для Ubuntu 16.04.7 **v2.9.xxxx**, в то время как для последней версии Docker'а требуется минимум **3.2.хххх**. Попытки обновить ядро на текущей машине ни к чему не привели, т.к. система виртуализации OpenVZ не позволяет это делать. Пришлось переходить на VDS (KVM). После обновления ядра до  версии **5.10.0**-051000rc6-generic, всё прошло как по маслу. Ещё раз все спасибо.

Comment: примите ответ галочкой слева, чтобы вопрос не висел открытым

Comment: Пробовал. Пишет - Вы сможете принять свой ответ через 19 часов.

Comment: хорошо, понял вас

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.7 на ядре v2.9.xxxx? Очень странно, там 4.4 уже при установке. Ну и хостер...

Comment: Хостер  https://firstbyte.ru/vps-vds/ovz-ssd/ . Самая новая версия ubuntu  16.04. Видимо с того года и не обновляли. Благо что на VDS (KVM) можно ставить любое ядро.

Comment: Проверил ядро на другом сервере OpenVZ там же. Команда _uname -r_ показала **2.6.32-042stab120.16**. Предполагаю, что это ограничение для работы OpenVZ.

Comment: Я посмотрел как работает OpenVZ. Кратко: для всех VDS на основе OpenVZ одно и то же ядро. Причем [очень старое](https://wiki.openvz.org/Download/kernel). `Так как при контейнеризации ядро является общим для всех контейнеров, изменить настройки ядра, обновить его или использовать дополнительные модули ядра невозможно.` - [отсюда](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/merion_networks/sravnenie-tehnologii-virtualizacii-openvz-kvm-i-xen-5f09d75f93336a7cc92e1a3d). Вот ответ на ваш вопрос на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35951482/9435985)